# Enzyme onClick doesn't work while testing react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test if an onClick event will change the imageName in this component:

```
  <Button
    Component={useAnchorTag ? "a" : "button"}
    {...btnProps}
  >
    {content}
    {showCaretIcon && (
      <Icon
        Component="span"
        imageName={`icon-${drawerIsOpen ? "up" : "down"}`}
      />
    )}
  </Button>
```

OnClick event is passed to btnProps from a parent component and also can be passed from an item, so originally I have 2 functions onClick event.

Here is my test :

```
  test("can render footer link with an icon up", () => {
    matchMedia.match("lg");

    card.moreInfoContent = [{
      content: "View More",
      showCaretIcon: true,
      onClick: e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Clicked")
      }
    }];
    const instance = mount(<CollapsibleCard data={card} />);
    const buttonWithIcon = instance.find(FooterLink).find('.footerLinkButton').last();
    buttonWithIcon.simulate("click");
    act(() => {
      expect(
        instance
          .find(FooterLink)
          .find(Button)
          .find(Icon)
          .prop("imageName")
      ).toBe("icon-up");
    });
  });
```

So looks like that when I add mock onClick to moreInfoContent, the default onClick function is overwritten, and I'm not sure how to avoid it. The default function is a hook that set's `drawerIsOpen` to true. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice--I'm not really sure what `card` is in the test and I'm left to guess the `CollapsibleCard` component's props and state. It's not clear to me how the handler is being used in the component. Thanks.

Comment: So why do you mock the `onClick` prop anyway?